# Data lost after clipping raster layer with drawn rectange, not another layer

Tags: raster, clip

I am trying to clip a raster layer which has a CRS of `EPSG:4326`, WGS 84. The data disappears after I clip it. I am not using a polygon from another layer; I just drew a rectangle to select the area.

Here is the text in the clip window:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 32.6739583333 15.3614583333 48.2708333333 3.28645833333 -of GTiff "/home/ross/saffron/Climate data/QGIS/New QGIS from WC/wc2.0_30s_tmax/wc2.0_30s_tmax_01.tif" "Jan T max Ethiopia"
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to say I have QGIS 2.18.11 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Not sure, but your output file does not show the relevant path to it. You might have named the `Output file` without specifying where to save (it requires clicking on `Select` button at the right hand side).

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. There's an [edit] button below your post that allows you to add information.

Comment: Thanks @Ross glad you solved it. When you have time will you post the steps you have taken as answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I did not choose a place for the file to end up. So, I

1. clicked on "Select" next to the output file box
2. typed my chosen file name into the window that popped up
3. clicked on the folder that I wanted the clipped raster to be in

That solved the problem.